# How to set cookies and redirect in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, cookies

I want to set a cookie, if a user visits Page "Test-2". When the cookie is set and the visitor tries to visit Page "Test" within 24 hours he should be automatically redirected to Page "Test-2".

Here is the Code I inserted to the function.php file of my Wordpress Theme:

```
if( is_page('test-2’)){
    if(isset($_COOKIE['dz_offer'])){
        $cookie = $_COOKIE['dz_offer'];
    }
else{
    setcookie('dz_offer', time() + 60*60*24, '/');
    }
}

if( is_page('test‘)){   
    if (isset($_COOKIE['dz_offer‘])){
        header(„Location: https://esample.com/test-2“);
        exit;
    }
}
```

However now I've the following error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'dz_offer' (T_STRING)"

Any ideas how to fix this and get it working?

Thanks for your help!

**+++ UPDATE +++**

The Error is gone now. However the cookie isn't stored, when I visit page "test-2"

Here is the updated Code I'm using:

```
if( is_page('test-2')){
if(isset($_COOKIE['dz_offer'])){
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['dz_offer'];
}
else{
setcookie('dz_offer',$val, time() + 60*60*24, '/');
}
}

if( is_page('test')){   
if (isset($_COOKIE['dz_offer'])){
    header("Location: https://example.com/test-2");
    exit;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors. Everywhere you put a ` instead of '

```
if( is_page('test-2')){
if(isset($_COOKIE['dz_offer'])){
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['dz_offer'];
}
else{
//cookies should be changed in the following way and $val is the value you have to save in the cookie 'dz_offer'.
setcookie('dz_offer',$val, time() + 60*60*24);
}
}

if( is_page('test')){   
if (isset($_COOKIE['dz_offer'])){
    header("Location: https://esample.com/test-2");
    exit;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks the error is gone! However there is no cookie set, when I visit page "test-2"...

Comment: @LukasLang, I have updated my ans.plz check

Comment: Thanks for your help! However the cookie still isn't set...

Comment: @LukasLang What value u want to save in the cookie should be stored in $val  eg.$val = 3, then $_cookie["dz_offer"] will have a value of 3